# ANGULAR 4 routing issue: No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Hi I have a login component that contains link to the register component.

When I click on this link I got this issue:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HttpClient!
Error: No provider for HttpClient!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/co...
```

The login component is well loaded, the register fails.

on the login component html I have:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/register']" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
```

my app routing looks like this:

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

The versions I am using:
    Node.js version:    v8.5.0
    NPM version:        5.4.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure `HttpClientModule` is listed in `imports`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, ...],
})
export class AppModule{}
```

See also https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

Make sure HttpModule and routing is listed in imports.